# Limit of a complex function definition

Tags: complex-analysis

I just want to check if my method for calculating limits of complex functions is correct:

The limit as $z\rightarrow a$ of $f(z)$ is $w$ if $$\lim_{z\rightarrow a} |f(z)-w| = 0.$$ Where $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}$ means $|z-a| \rightarrow 0$.

However when $z\rightarrow infty$, do we keep the same definition? Or is it $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} f(z) = w$ if $|f(z)-w| \rightarrow 0$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: If you think about limits at $\infty$ in the Riemann Sphere sense, the definition is the same at $\infty$.

Comment: And if we are consider just the plane?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two usual ways to do this (both considering a single point at infinity on the complex plane). We assume $w\in\Bbb C$.

1. Define $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z):=\lim_{z\to 0}\ f\left(\frac1z\right)$.
2. Use $|z|\to\infty$ to interpret the clause '$z\to\infty$', as you suggest, i.e. in the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ fashion, let $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=w$ iff
   $$\forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists M>0:\ \ |z|>M \implies |f(z)-w|<\varepsilon$$